# k-ng-model on dropdownlist not binding elsewhere

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am trying to do something that should be fundamental to Angular.  I want two controls that are bound to the same scope object to change with each other.  In my case the "master" is a kendo-drop-down-list while the "slave" is a small text section that should change value when the dropdownlist changes.  What am I missing that I can't get this to work?

I have a kendo-drop-down-list specified on my page via an angular directive.  I define the typical 'Name' and 'ID' fields and it displays the dropdownlist just fine using either ng-model or k-ng-model in the html.

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list
        k-data-text-field="'Name'"
        k-data-value-field="'ID'"
        k-auto-bind="false"
        k-data-source='itemtypesDataSource'
        id="ddxitemtypes" k-ng-model="itemtype" k-value-primitive="false"></select>
```

I want the selected text of the dropdownlist to show in a different area:

```
    <small>{{itemtype.Name}}</small>
```

My understanding of the k-ng-model is it points to the original object and I should be able to use dot notation to specify a field.  That is not working.  I have tried many different variations and read multiple other postings on here.  One of them will show the "ID" field but none show the "Name" field that I desire.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue for me?  I am trying to use Angular as it should be and want to avoid using events like 'on-change'.  Otherwise why use Angular at all?

Comment: I believe I understand I may be using k-ng-model incorrectly for a DropDownList and that I am incorrect about being able to specify a field to bind to.  I went ahead and set it up to listen to the event and I am setting a different scope value from that.  I still hope someone responds with information that clears this up for me since I believe there must be a more "pure" angular-kendo way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you were on the right track...
I can't really tell what is wrong from your example.  Here is a working example in plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/jVPXWzkeHP9snbas8Kdq?p=preview

My datasource looks like this...

```
$scope.itemtypesDataSource = {data: [
    { ID: 1, Name: 'Basketball' },
    { ID: 2, Name: 'Football' },
    { ID: 3, Name: 'Tennis' }]};
```

With HTML...

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list
    k-data-text-field="'Name'"
    k-data-value-field="'ID'"
    k-auto-bind="false"
    k-data-source='itemtypesDataSource'
    id="ddxitemtypes" k-ng-model="itemtype" k-value-primitive="false"></select>
    <small>{{itemtype.ID}} </small>
    <small>{{itemtype.Name}}</small>
```

Comment: Brandon, thanks for doing a sanity check for me.  Apparently I'm crazy! ;o)  I see your plunkr working and it is very heartening for me to see.  However my problem still does not readily become apparent.  I will play with yours and mine to see what gets it done.  I'll repost here if I figure it out.  In the meantime I will mark this as the answer since it _does_ work.  Thanks!